# Get Gmail addressbook in my site

Tags: jsp, authentication, email, gmail, grails

My application is fetching all the contacts of my gmail account. i try this using GoogleAPI. i got success.
but when i am trying to access gmail it will redirect to gmail login page. i do not want to gmail login page instead i want my login page. so how to override gmail login page . please help me out.